How to feed DeepFace.find() the faces extracted by DeepFace.extract_faces()?
I'm creating a face recognition script that process a list of photos and check if the face has a match in the database.
If Yes, add the cropped face to its matched folder in the database.
If No, add the cropped face to new folder called NewFace_01.
My question is:
How to feed DeepFace.find() the faces extracted by DeepFace.extract_faces() ?
as when I run DeepFace.find() with image path it works successfully, but I couldn't figure a way to give it the faces extracted by DeepFace.extract_faces()
Any ideas ?
When I try:
extracted_face = DeepFace.extract_faces(img_path=img_path)
res = DeepFace.find(img_path=extracted_face['face'], db_path=db_path)

It gives me this error:
ValueError: Face could not be detected in numpy array. Please confirm that the picture is a face photo or consider to set enforce_detection param to False.
I was expecting it to read the extracted face and find a matches of it in the Database as when I feed it image_path
The photo is definitely has a face. but I think i'm giving it a different data type or i have to convert the extracted_face to numpy array or something !??!

Exception message is clear. You need to set enforce_detection argument to false while calling find. Besides, you don't have to call extract_faces and find respectively. Find handles this already.
import cv2

dfs = DeepFace.find(
   img_path=img_path,
   db_path=db_path,
   enforce_detection=False
)

for df in dfs:
   # df is a pandas dataframe
   for index, instance in df.iterrows():
      source_path = instance["identity"]
      source_img = cv2.imread(source_path)

      # extract facial area of the source image
      x = instance["target_x"]
      y = instance["target_y"]
      w = instance["target_w"]
      h = instance["target_h"]
      source_img = source_img [y:y+h, x:x+w]


IMHO you should either use
extracted_face = DeepFace.extract_faces(img_path=img_path)

getting an face data object or
res = DeepFace.find(img_path=img_path, db_path=db_path)

but feeding key var img_path with the same img_path being used at extract_faces

That is true for normal cases, but my workflow require to extract all the faces from an image and then feed these faces to DeepFace.find() so when the face has no match I can crop it and add it to the database as new face. because DeepFace.find alone doesn't return the the face coordinate of unmatched faces and therefore I can't crop the unmatched face to add it to the database.
What I'm doing now to solve this problem is to perform DeepFace.find() and if the face has no match, run DeepFace.extract_faces()
but this is not efficient as it waste lot of time exacting the faces again.
